# VS Code - Why is my Jupyter Notebook UI a bit different from official docs?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I'm using the latest VS Code version 1.56 (April 2021) and I installed the official [Jupyter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter) extension of version v2021.6.811652604, which is also the latest version.

In the [version 1.56 update notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_56#_toggle-line-numbers), there's a screenshot showing the UI of a Jupyter Notebook:

[image: docs UI]

As you can see, the cell input UI contains a toolbar at the top right corner and there's also two buttons ("+ Code" and "+ Markdown") at the cell's bottom.

However, it seems like my VS Code Jupyter extension is still using the old UI. When I create a new notebook by running the Command Palette command `Jupyter: Create New Blank Notebook`, here's what the UI looks like in my VS Code:

[image: my UI]

Even when I'm hovering over the cell, I cannot see the toolbar at the top right corner similar to that in the update notes. Also, I see no "+ Code" and "+ Markdown" buttons.

Can anyone explain why this is the case? Do I need to use VS Code Insiders in order to get the UI in the first screenshot? Thanks a lot!

#### Update 1

I have updated my Jupyter Notebook using `pip install notebook --upgrade` and still VS Code is having the old UI as shown in the second screenshot

Comment: It is most likely required to install [Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/) vscode version since notebook api is not yet stable.

Comment: Check your `Notebook: Cell Toolbar Location` setting.  It should default to `right` but possibly yours is set to `hidden`.

Comment: @Mark Mine is set to `right` by default, but still the toolbar is not showing up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5590193/alex)'s comment, the reason is that the first screenshot is taken under [VS Code Insiders Edition](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/), in which it is using the [Notebook API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/notebook) to add more UI components  and functionalities to the Jupyter Notebook.

According to the Notebook API documentation:

> Note: The Notebook API is still proposed and under development, which
> means it is **only available on VS Code Insiders** and requires adding
> `vscode.proposed.d.ts` to your extension project.

Since I'm using the stable release of VS Code, Notebook API is not available yet and hence it's still using the old UI.

Comment: Mine was updated recently to the new UI and it doesn't work correctly with IPython display, how would one revert back to the older version?

Comment: The last version of the extension with the old UI is 2021.8.1054968649. Go to VS Code then extensions, click the cog icon on Jupyter Extension and select 'install another version'. Then simply copy and paste the version number mentioned above. ([Source](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter&ssr=false#review-details) - Find Jerzy Słomkowski's comment)